# What is a percentage sign in a terminal?

Tags: php, terminal

When I run the following in a terminal, I always get a % sign at the end.

What does `%` mean?

```
# 0014.php
<?php
echo "Hi there.\n";
echo "This is the second line.";
?>
```

Then in my terminal I run `php 0014.php`.

```
➜  cd phptest
➜  phptest git:(master) ✗ php 0014.php
Hi there.
This is the second line.%
```

Comment: How do you execute the script? Just `php 0014.php` or in some other way? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: `phptest` - what is it?

Comment: PHP doesn't support "\n".If you want a new line you can use html br tag.<?php echo '</br>';?>

Comment: @BuddhiEashwarage PHP does support `\n`...

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Is it?But i tried that.It didn't worked for both php single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: @BuddhiEashwarage They have to be in double quotes (`"\n"`). In single quotes the characters will simply be printed out. That is just how PHP strings work.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen But i tried with double quotes too.It didn't worked.

Comment: Put a \n at the end of your second line.

Comment: @cecilg23 It also didn't worked.

Comment: Use `PHP_EOL` wherever possible to have cross-platform compatibility. Don't bother to choose from `\n` `\r\n` `<br />`